# Filtering GraphAPI Query to retrieve only the Inbox Mailfolder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to filter my GraphAPI query to return only MailFolders that have the displayName "Inbox." From what I can tell, this should be fairly easy with:
`requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter`
But I think my filter command is incorrect, and I'm struggling to find documentation on the proper way to write this.

I've tried following the steps here, but I don't understand what i:i or s:s do, and any time I run the command below, no results are returned:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=csharp

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried:

```
return _appClient.Users[userID].MailFolders.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) => {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "displayName/any(i:i eq 'Inbox')";
        });
```

and expected it to return only the inbox folder for the given user, but instead it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`displayName` is not a collection, so no need to use `any` operator

```
return _appClient.Users[userID].
       MailFolders
       .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) => {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "displayName eq 'Inbox'";
        });
```

But I would prefer to use [well-known folder names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0#:%7E:text=a%20delta%20function.-,Well%2Dknown%20folder%20names,-Outlook%20creates%20certain)

```
return _appClient.Users[userID].MailFolders["Inbox"].GetAsync()
```